# блоки try-catch. Обработка исключений

Tags: java, исключения, try-catch

правильно ли я понимаю, что если первое закрытие выбросит ошибку, то остальные даже и не вызовутся? подскажите как ПРАВИЛЬНО исправить, а главное почему именно так!

```
private void closeStatement() throws DaoException, SQLException {
    try {
        getByIdStmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DaoException("Error! getByIdStmt is not closed");
    }
    try {
        updateStmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DaoException("Error! updateStmt is not closed");
    }
    try {
        addStmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DaoException("Error! addStmt is not closed");
    }
    try {
        deleteStmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DaoException("Error! deleteStmt is not closed");
    }
    System.out.println("Statement close");
}
```

Comment: А что значит правильно? Что должен выбросить метод, если не получилось закрыть 2 statement?

Comment: @vp_arth по задумке должна появиться надпись что 2 statement не закрыт и после этого закрываются 3 и 4.

Comment: Тогда просто замените выброс DaoException на вывод надписи.

Comment: @vp_arth я ведь правильно понял, что если я выкину DaoException, то остальные statement вызываться не будут?

Comment: Да, всё верно. Исключение всплывёт до следующего(по стеку) try-catch, если он есть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно, так:

```
private void closeStatement() throws DaoException, SQLException {
    ArrayList<String> err = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        getByIdStmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        err.add("getByIdStmt");
    }
    try {
        updateStmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        err.add("updateStmt");
    }
    try {
        addStmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        err.add("addStmt");
    }
    try {
        deleteStmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        err.add("deleteStmt");
    }
    if (!err.isEmpty()) {
      throw new DaoException("Error! "+String.join(", ", err)+" not closed");
    }
    System.out.println("Statement close");
}
```

Поочерёдно пытаемся закрыть все statement, неудачи собираем. Потом выбрасываем общее для всех ошибок исключение.

Comment: err бы проинициализировать еще

Comment: @etki, действительно)

Comment: @etki подскажите. не срабатывает StringUtils.join(err.toArray(), пишет 
"Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'java.lang.Object[]', required: 'java.util.Collection' less... 
join(java.util.Collection,String) in StringUtils cannot be applied to
(java.lang.Object[], String) "

Comment: @Oleg скорее всего `.toArray()` достаточно будет убрать

Comment: @Oleg, в java8 можно `String.join(", ", err)`

Comment: @etki и vp_arth подскажите, а можно ли обойтись без коллекции и например просто выбросить первое исключение которое встретилось?

Comment: @Oleg нет, тогда же не выполнятся последующие выражения

Comment: @Oleg Можно вообще ничего не выбрасывать - просто логировать ошибки. Всё равно вы не собираетесь их обрабатывать.

Comment: @etki а такой [вариант] (https://pp.userapi.com/c639918/v639918509/129fe/1P4q_gnfQPI.jpg) сработает?

Comment: @Oleg так вы ничего не словите. Вам стоит определиться, чего именно вы хотите от кода, и уже от этого отталкиваться.

Comment: @etki цикл оборвется на первом throw так ведь?
так что необходимо просто выбрасывайте первое исключение которое встретилось

Comment: @Oleg я сейчас не вижу ни одного цикла

Comment: @etki извините, писал другой код и параллельно сюда. Вы правы тут нет цикла.
необходимо просто выбросить первое исключение которое встретилось.

Comment: @Oleg тогда все остальные выражения не будут выполнены, и вы останетесь с незакрытыми prepared statements. Так себе идея.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56328/discussion-between-oleg-and-etki).